# How to find date YYYY-MM-DD in file txt

Tags: java, regex

This is my string

> 2007-01-12Jakistxt2008-01-31xxx2008-02-292008-15-102008-19-452009-05-0120999-11-11pppp2001-00-0109-01-012001-01-002009-01-1112009-02-291998-11-11

I tried find date in format `YYYY-MM-DD` . I know that directly it is not possible. 
I managed print this result

```
2007-01-12
2008-01-31
2008-02-292
2008-19-452
0999-11-11
2001-00-010
2001-01-002
2009-02-291 



     String regex4="\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2,3}";
     Pattern wzor4=Pattern.compile(regex4);
     Pattern wzor5=Pattern.compile(regex5);

    Matcher efekt4=wzor4.matcher(wyrazenie);
    String rezultat4="";

    while (efekt4.find()) {
        list422.add(efekt4.group());

    }
    for(int i=0;i<list422.size();i++) System.out.println(list422.get(i));`
```

Comment: It's not yet clear what you want to reach, and what exactly is wrong with your solution so far. E.g. do you want to reject dates that don't exist?

Comment: Isn't your problem solved by just changing `String regex4="\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2,3}";` to `String regex4="\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}";`?

Comment: Also.. are your variable names just you mashing the keyboard? If so, that's terrible

Comment: @NathanLoyer The variable names are perfect Polish words. Miroslaw, when creating [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for an English language web site, it’s probably better to do it in English. Also, Miroslaw, what is the desired reult from your example string?

Comment: Ah ok. I don't know any Polish. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You seem to have some sequences in the input which are not valid dates.  I would suggest `"\\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"`.  (I know that doesn’t handle varying month lengths, but I doubt that that level of accuracy is needed here.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `(?(?<=^)|(?<=\D))\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?(?=$)|(?=\D))`.

It uses `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` to match your strng format.

Also, the date cannot be followed or preceeded by any digit:

`(?(?<=^)|(?<=\D))` - it's conditional look-behind: if we are at the beginning of the string, then start matching, if not, make sure that what's before is not a digit (`\D`)

`(?(?=$)|(?=\D))` - it's look-ahead analogical to look-behind.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CfNF7G/1)

Alternatively, you could use just `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}`, which would also match adjacent to each other.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CfNF7G/2)

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you could explain the pattern.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff You're right, I was just adding description :)

Comment: In the sample text, there are valid dates immediately adjacent to one another. OP didn't specify if he wants them or not.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff I added alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

I put it   `String regex4="(?(?<=^)|(?<=\D))\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?(?=$)|(?=\D))";`

and Eclipse said

```
 Unknown inline modifier near index 2
```

(?(?<=^)|(?<=\D))\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?(?=$)|(?=\D))
  ^